# how can I dismiss first vc that second has presented modally on the first vc

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I have a view controller that named "firstVC" and another one that named "secondVC" . the secondVC will present modally on the first vc I want to dismiss firstVC and secondVC when user push the button on the secondVC
I call the method here But it does execute But nothing will happen 
in the secondVC this will happen

```
firstVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if you suggest me to use delegate please tell me how can I use that completely ? I don't know what should I put in the firstVC or what should I put in the secondVC

**one more thing**

In some other cases I need to execute json in the firstVC and when json has complete the both view controllers (firstVC and secondVC) be dismiss how can I do that too ?

Comment: How do you present firstVC? Is firstVC root view controller?

Comment: all of the vc's are in story board

Comment: Have you tried `firstVC.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` ?

Comment: @OOPer this does not worked for me

Comment: Please explain _not worked_. What happened?

Comment: nothing will happen ( the page won't dismiss) I used break point (this line will execute But noting will happen)

Comment: because presentingViewController is nil here

Comment: so how can I do that ( that the app detect that should dismiss that view controller)

Comment: Seems you are presenting `firstVC` in an unusual manner. Please try to show more context, for example, are they embedded in a navigation controller? Please explain all such things.

Comment: let me tell you more about that : I have main page that the view controllers will present modally one after another in front of each other for example first VC will present modally on the main page and second VC will present modally on the first VC and third VC will present modally on the second VC and .... so when I dismiss the last and in front VC I want to dismiss all VC's except the main page

Comment: Then you need to do just `mainPage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` .

Comment: I used @Moayad Al kouz code and that's worked for me But thank you for attention and helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using delegate:

```
protocol DismissDelegate{
    func dismissVC()
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DismissDelegate{

    func showSecondVC(){
        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        secondVC.delegate = self
    }

    func dismissVC(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController{
    var delegate: DismissDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate?.dismissVC()
    }
}
```